# MinGW with GCC on Windows misreporting numeric values

Tags: c, windows, gcc, printf, mingw

For some reason, whenever I use a numeric value in my compiler set-up (MinGW on Windows, using a CMD prompt to compile and run), it completely misreports numbers in the program.

Code example:

```
//C hello world example
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int value;
    value = 10;
    printf("The number is %d \n"), value;


     int value2;
     value2 = -100;
     printf("The number is %d \n"), value2;
     return 0;
}
```

Cf. [screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4EDc.png).

Comment: put `value` *inside* `printf(..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By saying

```
printf("The number is %d \n"), value;
```

you're somehow making (mis)use of the ["comma operator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) , so no syntax error is produced. Your print statement is *considered* as

```
printf("The number is %d \n");
```

and `value` si executed as a void expression.

Now, `printf()` being a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), it does not check for the required number of arguments for supplied format specifiers (by default), but, point to note, as per the required format for `printf()`, you're essentially missing out the operand to the `%d` format specifier. This  in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As the standard mandates

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined.

The correct syntax will be

```
 printf("The number is %d \n", value);
```

where the `value` will be the argument to `%d` format specifier.

***Moral of the story: Enable compiler warning and pay heed to them.***

---

Note:  Some suggestions,

1. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(int argc, char**argv)`, or, *atleast* `int main(void)`.
2. Try to get into a habit of defining and initialize any variable at the same time. Will save you from the danger of ending up using uninitialized value (*local variables*) at later part.

Comment: An even more recommended signature for `main` is `int main(int argc, char**argv)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You're very right sir, but that will be useful only if we intend to use `argc` or `argv` in our code, otherwise, it's kind of useless, isn't it?

Comment: It is a very good habit to have. And I like a lot the [GNU convention](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html) of requiring both `--help` and `--version` to be understood. Even my `/bin/true` on GNU/Linux understands them. At last `argv[0]` is very useful to use in error messages... So in real life `main` *always* uses `argc` and `argv` so practically `int main(void)` is wrong (even if acceptable by some legacy C standard) !

Comment: So the recommended signature of `main` is *not* `int main (void)` -this is obsolete and deprecated, user-unfriendly, useless, should never be taught to newbies, but sadly was permitted in the previous century- but *really* `int main(int argc, char**argv)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so you mean to say `C11` is the **"obsolete and deprecated"** standard?

Comment: Standards are not the same as good habit. The C11 standard allows you to name all your functions `f01`, `f02`, `f03` .... but you really should not do that in real life (for human written and maintained code). It is however useful to do in machine generated C code. So we should not teach newbies about `int main (void)` but about `int main(int argc, char**argv)` - and even tell them about the [GNU conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html) that most proprietary software also follows...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sir, I never said you are wrong, rather I also think the same way, but then again, just can't agree with the "obsolete and deprecated" part. Your suggestion is genuine and valid, nevertheless.

Comment: Then you should edit your answer to say that (and I removed my upvote, will add it again after your edit)

Answer (score 6):

`value` and `value2` have to be passed as arguments, i.e. **within the parantheses**. Change it to the following:

```
printf("The number is %d \n", value);
```

And do similarly with `value2`.

Once again, this shows that compiling with `-Wall` and `-pedantic` switches on is useful. GCC most likely would have issued a warning message.

Comment: as you deleted a post on another thread that had a +1 I have replaced it here. You did the right thing so should not be punished for it